# How I can write a list or string to a specific column csv file by using python?

Tags: python, csv

How I can write a list or string to a specific column csv file by using python?

```
txt_file = path+"allfils"
csv_file = path+"mycsv.csv"
in_txt = open(txt_file, "r")
out_csv = open(csv_file, 'w')
file_string = in_txt.read()
file_list = file_string.split(',')
writer = csv.writer(out_csv)
writer = csv.DictWriter(out_csv,['Script Name', 'description',extrasaction='ignore')

writer.writeheader()

for row in file_list:
    out_csv.writelines(row)
```

so under 'Script Name' rows should have only script names and then in 'description' column I want to put only descriptions.

description is a list of multiple descriptions
if I do this, I get descriptions as rows under same column "Script name' under every script

```
Script Name 
a.tcl
description1
description2
b.tcl
description1
description2
```

but I want to see script name and description in their columns as below

```
Script Name                   Description
a.tcl                         description1, description2
b.tcl                         description1, description2
```

Comment: what does your input file look like?  you read in the file as a single string, then split it with "," which looks like it is giving you an array of strings.  you are then iterating over it with your "for row in" line and writing each string as a line...

Comment: Yes I am reading a file which has all script names on separate lines, the code to get description from these scripts which are mentioned in txt file is missing in description. that code returns me a list of descriptions.

Comment: if they only have the script names where are you getting your descriptions from?

Comment: I will open all these scripts one by one and read descriptions and then write those descriptions to csv against respective script names in csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that when you csv_out.writerow you are passing it a array of 2 elements where the first element is the script name and the second second element is a single string of all your descriptions.

Comment: I have a list of descriptions and a string of name, when I write both to csv, description is getting filled in correct column. I converted list of descriptions to a string and then concatenated with name and then wrote to csv, it gave me first description of first name in correct column but other descriptions of same name is filled in other columns, I wanted to fill all descriptions in same column as of first description. how I can do that?

Comment: you need to make sure you escape the , between the descriptions.  otherwise anything parsing the CSV will think it is a new column